# Stuck with an interview Question... Partitioning of an Array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I found the following problem on the internet, and would like to know how I would go about solving it:

> **Problem:** Integer Partition without Rearrangement
>
> **Input:** An arrangement S of non negative numbers {s<sub>1</sub>, . . .
>   , s<sub>n</sub>} and an integer k.
>
> **Output:** Partition S into k or fewer ranges, to minimize the maximum
>   of the sums of all k or fewer ranges,
>   without reordering any of the
>   numbers.*

Please help, seems like interesting question... I actually spend quite a lot time in it, but failed to see any solution..

Comment: This isn't C++ or C specific- or if you want a solution then you must tag only C or C++.

Comment: What do you mean "over all the ranges"?

Comment: Will `n` be >= `k`? @Tim: Considering that the maximum sum of all values won't change regardless of how integers are summed, he likely is referring to the sums of the values contained within each partition.

Comment: `minimize the maximum sum over all the ranges` - what does that even mean

Comment: @sehe, I think it means to partition the set so as to minimize the sum of the partition with the maximum sum.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That sounds right. thx for being my external reading comprehension extender. (English is not my native language)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's try to solve the problem using dynamic programming.

**Note: If *k > n* we can use only *n* intervals.**

Let consider *d[ i ][ j ]* is solution of the problem when *S* = {*s<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *s<sub>i</sub>* } and *k* = *j*. So it is easy to see that:

1. *d[ 0 ][ j ] = 0* for each *j* from *1* to *k*
2. *d[ i ][ 1 ] = sum(s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>)* for each *i* from *1* to *n*
3. *d[ i ][ j ] = min<sub>for t = 1 to i</sub> (max ( d[i - t][j - 1], sum(s<sub>i - t + 1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>)) for i = 1 to n and j = 2 to k*

**Now let's see why this works:**

1. When there is no elements in the sequence it is clear that only one interval there can be (an empty one) and sum of its elements is 0. That's why *d[ 0 ][ j ] = 0* for all *j* from *1* to *k*.
2. When only one interval there can be, it is clear that solution is sum of all elements of the sequence. So *d[ i ][ 1 ] = sum(s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>)*.
3. Now let's consider there are *i* elements in the sequence and number of intervals is *j*, we can assume that last interval is (s<sub>i - t + 1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>) where *t* is positive integer not greater than *i*, so in that case solution is *max ( d[i - t][j - 1], sum(s<sub>i - t + 1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>)*, but as we want the solution be minimal we should chose *t* such to minimize it, so we will get *min<sub>for t = 1 to i</sub> (max ( d[i - t][j - 1], sum(s<sub>i - t + 1</sub>...s<sub>i</sub>))*.

**Example:**

*S = (5,4,1,12), k = 2*

*d[0][1] = 0, d[0][2] = 0*

*d[1][1] = 5, d[1][2] = 5*

*d[2][1] = 9, d[2][2] = 5*

*d[3][1] = 10, d[3][2] = 5*

*d[4][1] = 22, d[4][2] = 12*

**Code:**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    const int INF = 2 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> s(n + 1);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        cin >> s[i];
    vector<int> first_sum(n + 1, 0);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        first_sum[i] = first_sum[i - 1] + s[i];
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    vector<vector<int> > d(n + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        d[i].resize(k + 1);
    //point 1
    for(int j = 0; j <= k; ++j)
        d[0][j] = 0;
    //point 2
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        d[i][1] = d[i - 1][1] + s[i]; //sum of integers from s[1] to s[i]
    //point 3
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        for(int j = 2; j <= k; ++j)
        {
            d[i][j] = INF;
            for(int t = 1; t <= i; ++t)
                d[i][j] = min(d[i][j], max(d[i - t][j - 1], first_sum[i] - first_sum[i - t]));
        }


    cout << d[n][k] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mihran - Seems good.. can you provide example for your approach.. it wud be more clearer ....

Comment: Ok @AGeek I'll edit my answer a bit later, providing more clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Bro. I am waiting for your clear explanation with example... :)

Comment: Pure mathematical explanation... kind of confused in ur DP Solution.. can you provide examples, also i am very curious to learn DP by heart... how is this maths working.. i want to get on with a discussion bro??

Comment: Wait bro.. i m like off from my mind now.. staying back late in offc.. It looks pretty awesm soln, but m just trying to focus on it.. give me smtime.. :)

Comment: can you provide more clarity on 3rd point..... also how are you calculating sum d[4][2]... ??

Comment: Bro m still figuring out your 3point.. and i thnk you k=3 and lil' bigger list(n=8 or so) wud make me understand the sol surely... plz bro.. m almost there....

Comment: @AGeek when number of intervals is `j` => that if we drop last interval, then their number will be `j - 1` and assuming that last interval is last `t` numbers we getting that formula, which should be minimized relative to t.

Comment: Ya bro.. Thanks a lot for you efforts and helping me on this prob.. code will be helpfull.. i understood the problem almost.. code wud definately help as i can input sm test cases n get back to you..

Comment: Also,, you seems to have awesome DP concepts.. What approach shud be followed to start thinking DP? can we chat on stackoverflow if i found any confusion in DP?

Comment: @AGeek I've add code which implements solution of the problem. Think this is enough to test and understand how algorithm works.

Re: Chat. Not now, maybe next time. But I can tell you that best way to start thinking DP is participating to programming contests. Take a look to topcoder.com/tc :)

Comment: What does _d[0][i]_ mean when you've defined the sequence starting at 1: _S = {s1, ..., si }_

Comment: Thanks Mihran for your help and time... I left from office that time.. Wud definately love to get in touch wid u smtime... Thanks....

Comment: Hi Mihran you there, i need your help? can we chat?

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan shouldn't d[4][2] be 12? In fact, your program returns 12.

Comment: @ppvi seconding this! is d[4][2] supposed to be 12? if so then I understand the solution.

Comment: Yes @Harry there was a typo.

Answer (score 8):

This problem is taken verbatim from Steven Skiena's book "[The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/)". You can read the detailed discussion and his solution on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&pg=PA294). Better yet, [buy the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202).