# Given a multiset of n positive integers partition them into 17 parts such that the maximum sum of the parts is minimized

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a multiset of n positive integers partition them into 17 parts such that the maximum
sum of the parts is minimized.

I need the algorithm for the above question in time polynomial in n and
M, where M is the maximum element in the multiset. I have tried DP and would love to know if there is a DP algo which can solve this efficiently

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454598/stuck-with-an-interview-question-partitioning-of-an-array with k = 17. The runtime of the DP algorithm is O(n x M x k).

Comment: But there is a fundamental difference as in the above question reordering of numbers is prohibited but not in my question

Comment: This question allows us to reorder the elements. I think it is difficult than the question referred in above comment.