# Variation of knapsack (or partition) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

the question I have a problem is as follows:

Given a queue of N items, each with a weight, and the queue of K containers. And we need to partition the items to the containers in the order they came. For example, the very first item can only go to the first container, the second one can go to either the first or the second but not the third (otherwise the second container won't have any items).

I need to create and implement an algorithm that make some kind of uniform distribution, so the heaviest container must be as lightweight as it can; to give count of containers with such weight.

I suppose it is some variation of 3-partition or knapsack problem. I have already implemented one possible solution for distribution using dynamic programming and tried to get count from the table used in it. But it was not effective enough (too much memory expensive), and algorithm of getting the amount of containers wasn't correct.

Can someone explain, please, which algorithm is solution for this problem?

Comment: When `N > K`, can the last `N-K` items go in any container?

Comment: Does your problem not have more in common with the [Bin-Packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), or perhaps the more general [Cutting Stock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)?

Comment: @Andy Jones, no, every container should be used, and should be used in order. So we can put first 3 items to the first container, next 5 to the second, N-K should be distributed somehow between another containers. Or maybe I just didn't clearly understand your question.

Comment: @asQuirreL thanks, I'll read about this problems more

Comment: I might be missing something, but can your question be rephrased as ""Given a `n` element array, how can we partition it into `k` contiguous segments such that maximum sum of the elements of any segment is minimized?" Because if so, your question is a [repeat of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454598/stuck-with-an-interview-question-partitioning-of-an-array), which gives an efficient DP solution. Or are you looking for something even more efficient than that?

Comment: @AndyJones yes, that is exactly the same problem, and I had exactly the same solution, but it is not effective because of my solution (attempt to solve, to be honest) of the second part of problem - how to get the count of containers with this weight, so I need always keep whole table of unsigned long ints in memory. Or I need something more efficient in memory than that, or I need more effective and smart algorithm to get the count of containers.

Comment: How much more memory efficient are you wanting? Would linear in N and constant in K work?

Comment: @AndyJones Yes, it would be great. Now I have N*K memory efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the OP's problem in general can be solved by the DP algorithm given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454598/stuck-with-an-interview-question-partitioning-of-an-array). I'll repeat the crux of it here for completeness:

> Suppose *d[i][j]* is solution of the problem when we have items *s[1], .., s[i]*
>   and *j* containers. Then:
>
> 1. *d[0][j] = 0* for each *j*
> 2. *d[i][1] = Sum(s[1], ..., s[i])* for
>      each *i*
> 3. *d[i][j] = min(max(d[i-t][j-1], Sum(s[i-t+1], ..., s[i]) over all 1<=t<=i)*

However, the naive implementation consumes O(NK) space, which is too much. Fortunately, look at (3): `d[_][j]`'s value depends only on `d[_][j-1]`. This means that once we're done computing all `d[_][j]`, we can use the space we were using to store `d[_][j-1]` to instead store the values of `d[_][j+1]` we're about to compute.

Since the values `d[0][j]` are all zero, we don't need to store those either. Hence the only arrays we need to store are the O(N)-sized `d[i][1]`, the O(N)-sized array that holds the result from the `j-1`th iteration, and the O(N)-sized array that holds the results from the `j`th iteration we're currently computing. Total: O(N).

Edit: So first time round, I didn't actually answer the OP's question about how to count the number of containers at max weight. Suppose `w[i][j]` holds the max weight of the `i,j`th problem, and `c[i][j]` is the number of containers which match that max weight. Then:

1. `c[0][j] = j` and `w[0][j] = 0` for each `j`
2. `c[i][1] = 1` and `w[i][1] = Sum(s[1], .., s[i])` for each `i`
3. Let `u` be equal to the `t` chosen in pt (3) above.

   - If `d[i-u][j-1] > Sum(s[i-u+1], .., s[i])`:

     - then  `c[i][j] = c[i-u][j-1]` and `w[i][j] = w[i-u][j-1]`
     - because the `j`th container with weight `Sum(s[i-u+1], .., s[i]` is lighter than the heaviest container out of containers `1, .., j-1`, which has weight `d[i-u][j-1]`.
   - If `d[i-u][j-1] < Sum(s[i-u+1], .., s[i])`:

     - then `c[i][j] = 1` and `w[i][j] = Sum(s[i-u+1], .., s[i])`
     - because the `j`th container with items `s[i-u+1], .., s[i]` is the new heaviest container.
   - If  If `d[i-u][j-1] == Sum(s[i-u+1], .., s[i])`:

     - then `c[i][j] = c[i-u][j-1]+1` and `w[i][j] = d[i-u][j-1]`
     - because the `j`th container is the same weight as the previous heaviest container.

Again, we only need to use a constant number of `O(N)` sized arrays, for `O(N)` time overall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I understand, this algorithm provide us information about maximum weight. How can I get information about number of containers with such weight? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Completely forgot about that, sorry. Edited a solution in.